# How can I get the user email in a Microsoft Office JS Addin?

Tags: office-js

I would like to get the user email to check his credits in the service. Preferably without any SSO magic like we can in Google Docs addons https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`userProfile`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox.userProfile) object contains the member `emailAddress` which return String of the user's SMTP email address. This member available from 1.0 level of API and example of usage may looks like ...

```js
// Example: allieb@contoso.com
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    $(function () { 
        console.log(Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress);
    }
}
```

**Please note**: Current Office.js API for Word/Excel/PowerPoint doesn't offer functionality to retrieve user name/e-mail address.

Comment: Unfortunately no luck "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'userProfile' of undefined"

Comment: Your code must be inside initialization function of the Office. More is over here: [Understanding the JavaScript API for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/understanding-the-javascript-api-for-office). I'll change the example for you in a sec.

Comment: Much appreciated. Looks like this object is only available for Outlook addins. Unfortunately, no user id, or email or any identifier is available for the Word addin https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/understanding-the-javascript-api-for-office#mailbox-object

Comment: Looks like we must do the SSO magic to authenticate https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I thought you are talking about Outlook when referring to e-mail addresses. For any other Office products this info is not available: [How to get username, email address, filename from task pane app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36261336/how-to-get-username-email-address-filename-from-task-pane-app). I'll correct the answer once more.

Comment: @J.Lavoie I am sorry, I don't have insights.

Comment: @SlavaIvanov this code results in an email address that looks like this: outlook_6************D@outlook.com...is there any way to get the users actual email address and not the SMTP address? I would expect something like foo@bar.com to come back, not that unique outlook value.

Comment: @rocketlobster Per documentation the `emailAddress` is return SMTP e-mail address. I am not aware of the Office js API function which return aliases. You may want to look at REST API `GET: https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me` request, if it returns something you would want, but I believe the better way is just to create your own question and somebody may help you better. Best regards.