# Is it possible to get the logged user's username from power point web add-in?

Tags: office365, powerpoint, office-js, office-addins

We are working on a PowerPoint web add-in. Is there any way to get the logged user's Username from web add-in? we have searched a lot but didn't get a solution yet.  Any help would be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get username, email address, filename from task pane app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36261336/how-to-get-username-email-address-filename-from-task-pane-app)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. we are not using any Single sign-on (SSO)  mechanism in our system.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to get the user name from Word/Excel/PowerPoint. Your options are:

1. Single sign-on (SSO). Your add-in gets a token from the Office host application that contains a "preferred_username" property. The value of the property is the email of the user logged into Office.
2. [Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL)](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) to get the user's identity.

Take a look at the [How to get username, email address, filename from task pane app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36261336/how-to-get-username-email-address-filename-from-task-pane-app) page for more information.

Comment: We are not using any SSO mechanism in our existing system.  We will try with the second option (ADAL) and get back to you. Thank you